# Robomongo robo 3t - poorly readable text

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, mongodb

I do not know if this is a bug or setting.

I downloaded the program ([robo3t](https://robomongo.org/download)) to work with the mongo database. I use `Ubuntu 16.04` and have very little text. I use FullHD and the text is hardly readable.

Could someone please tell me if this is a bad program detection or setup, other programs work fine.

I have the same view on the other laptop where `Ubuntu 18.04` is installed. Friend has Windows and Mac and does not have this problem.

[here is a program view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V41Mj.png)

Comment: scroll whell didn't have any effet with `ctrl` shortcut?

Comment: @damadam Unfortunately, no :)

Comment: Robo3T has several open issues regarding [Hi-DPI Support](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/milestone/19) which are likely related to your FullHD problem. The Robo3T project isn't very actively maintained and is lagging in support for recent versions of MongoDB. I'd suggest looking for an actively updated alternative. Providing recommendations for alternative programs is [outside the scope](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) of questions for Ask Ubuntu, but you could try the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) StackExchange site.

Comment: @Stennie Thank you. My problem has been solved after updating Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS my problem has been solved. I have Robo3T 1.2.1.

Maybe some update of a package.